# Chrome hangs on pattern match (tinymce / magento2)

Tags: javascript, regex, tinymce, match, magento2

My chrome tab currently crashes/hangs if I use the "undo"-button of the tinymce editor within the magento 2 backend. The error only happens, if I use it within a huge `<table>`.

With debugging, I found out that the crash is caused by the following code:

```
while (source.length > 0) {
        if (match = source.match(pattern)) { // error happens here
            result += source.slice(0, match.index);
            result += String.interpret(replacement(match));
            source = source.slice(match.index + match[0].length)
        } else {
            result += source,
            source = ""
        }
}
```

In the situation of the crash, the pattern variable has the following content:

```
var pattern = /<([a-z0-9\-\_]+.+?)([a-z0-9\-\_]+=".*?\{\{.+?\}\}.*?".+?)>/i;
```

Now the source variable just contains a huge html table without anything specific, just links, images, text.

The error doesn't happen with smaller html contents, so it seems to be some kind of timeout/hang on that pattern.

Here's a jsfiddle of the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/sbbzcL9d/

The browser doesn't crash here because it's only the pattern matching, but it crashes within the tinymce/magento context.

Does anyone have an idea what's happening here?

Comment: Sidenote: Remove the `'`s, they shouldn't be there.

Comment: you're right, removed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is usually quite an expensive operation. In your fiddle, running your regexp on the 9969 characters long string required 1.98 seconds to complete.

[image]

In common rich text editors, the raw HTML string might be even longer. For example, the length of this page's HTML is about 145260 characters long. Assuming the time complexity is proportional, it would take about 30 seconds to compute.

My advice is try not to apply the regexp on an extremely long string. Instead, only apply it on the relevant parts.

Comment: Thanks for your input! unfortunately the call is from /vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/prototype/prototype.js and the function gsub(), seems like i'd have to change a lot of code to apply it only to relevant parts.